# How to use "standardized track listings" in Spotify apps

Tags: spotify

The Spotify UI guidelines for Spotify apps (at https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/design/) say "When listing tracks in your app, use our standardized track listings". I cannot find any examples in the documentation on how to use these "standardized track listings". By using the Inspector I have found classes in list.css (such as sp-list and sp-item) which it looks like I need to use but have not been able to work out quite how to use these to recreate the look of the Spotify track listings.
The Billboard Top Charts app appears to use track listings like I need, but I can't find ay way to see how they are doing this as the Inspector only works for your own apps as far as I can tell.

Does anybody have any advice or examples?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some examples

```
sp = getSpotifyApi(1);

var m = sp.require("sp://import/scripts/api/models");
var v = sp.require("sp://import/scripts/api/views");

// Example 1
var tpl = new m.Playlist();
var tempList = new v.List(tpl);
tpl.add(m.Track.fromURI("spotify:track:4z4t4zEn4ElVPGmDWCzRQf"));
tpl.add(m.Track.fromURI("http://open.spotify.com/track/7E8JGVhbwWgAQ1DtfatQEl"));
tpl.add(m.Track.fromURI("spotify:track:40YBc3mR3yyqyYvtesQOMj"));
tpl.add(m.Track.fromURI("spotify:local:Rolling+Stones:A+Bigger+Bang:Rain+Fall+Down:293"));

document.body.appendChild(tempList.node);

// Example 2
var pl = m.Playlist.fromURI("spotify:user:username:playlist:424km2k4m24");
var list = new v.List(pl);

document.body.appendChild(list.node);

// Example 3
var album = m.Album.fromURI("spotify:album:1vWnB0hYmluskQuzxwo25a");
var albumList = new v.List(album);
albumList.node.classList.add("album");

document.body.appendChild(albumList.node);
```

Comment: I've tried the examples but nothing was added in my app. Looking at the outerHTML property of the node property of the list gives:

    <div class="sp-list" tabindex="0"><div style="height: 0px; "></div></div>

Am I missing something? The playlist seems to contain the correct number of tracks, but the node is always empty like that.

Comment: Add
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="sp://import/css/core-dark.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="sp://import/css/api.css">`

Comment: And .sp-list { height: 400px; }

Comment: Many thanks, that did it. I had the right CSS references, but setting the height of the list caused it to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking, I had exactly the same question too!

I too get the issue where i get no actual content added - just the wrapper div. Not including api.css makes it work, but the list is obviously not styled. Including css/list.css directly breaks it too. Creating my own copy and selectively commenting out list.css I found the offending rule to be:

```
.sp-list > div {
```

if you change this to be

```
.sp-list {
```

then it renders fine. No idea what is going on. Obviously this solution is not idea because I've just duplicated what's meant to be a common resource...