# Is it possible to add more elements (or otherwise alter) to the entries in a standardized "list" view in a spotify app?

Tags: javascript, api, playlist, spotify

So I'm using the "standardized track listing" [in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608692/how-to-use-standardized-track-listings-in-spotify-apps), and which the guidelines instruct developers to use.

I can easily *remove* fields from each entry in the track listing with css (just display:none, etc), and likewise alter the general appearance.  However, I would like to *add* another field to each entry.

As an example, see the "Top Lists" feature in your spotify client (for me this is the second item under APPS).  These lists look mostly like normal playlists (and of course, operate as such too), but each element has a number next to it, and the format is a little bit different.

Would it be possible to do this in my own application, without totally reinventing the wheel?

I can do something like: `$(".sp-list a").each(function(){$(this).append("foo")})`  but that will only affect the currently visible tracks(ish).  If part of the playlist scrolls out of view, those tracks are not affected.  Also, if Spotify decides to redraw any part of the list, which *does* happen (for example if I scroll the affected items out of view and play a track), I lose the change.  So this is not especially viable/clean.

Thoughts?

Comment: Also, I guess as a follow-up (specifically directed to you spotify employees out there):  If I _do_ reinvent the wheel--ie, use the classes, etc that a real playlist uses, but with my own wrapper to let me mess with it-- (which is actually pretty easy now that I've messed around a bit), is that kosher? 

Or, is that a recipe for rejection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I were on a meeting with Spotify earlier today I asked them about this question.
There is no option to add elements to the list.node at this moment but they said they will look into the "problem".

Until then you will have to add your elements outside the list.node, either you could put it on top (together with position: absolute;) or you could put it before or after (with float) if your element should be the first or last column.

Comment: Thanks for the response...Did they give any indication as to whether or not using a faux-list.node that otherwise looks as its supposed to would be kosher or not?

Comment: They said that it's ok to make custom solutions where it can increase the user experience and make the app more functional. But each individual app (and custum solutions) will be reviewed, so I recommend you to talk with Spotify about your special needs so your app will be approved.

Answer (score 0):

By now, it is (kind of) possible; not very nicely but still. So just for reference:

Deleting fields: [Editing Time Field in a Spotify App Playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097104/editing-time-field-in-a-spotify-app-playlist)

Adding HTML:

```
//monkey-patch the views.Tracks class
var myTrackView = function (track) {
  views.Track.apply(this, arguments);
  this.node.appendChild($('<span>hi</span>')[0]);
}
myTrackView.prototype = views.Track.prototype;

//now tell the list to use this new class
var list = new views.List(playlist, function (track) {return new myTrackView(track)})
$('#playlist-placeholder').html(list.node)
```

You see the hi now appear on each row, and behave like any other part of the playlist.

Now, to save the extra information I want to show, I just add it to the track.data object, so that I can get to it from myTrackView.

Comment: I have to backtrack a bit on this: stuff that I set in the track.data object disappears after some time... So if you want to fill this field with stuff that's not 100% dependent on the track itself, you need to use some workaround....