# Editing Time Field in a Spotify App Playlist

Tags: spotify

I am having trouble removing the time field from a playlist in the Spotify App. I only want to display Song title, Artist and Album. Any help on this topic would be truly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify which track attributes to display using the List object. An example is here: http://deceptacle.com/2011/12/26/spotify-app-api-some-things/

```
var list = new views.List(playlist, function (track) {
    return new views.Track(track, views.Track.FIELD.NAME |
                views.Track.FIELD.ARTIST |
                views.Track.FIELD.ALBUM);
});
$("#playlist").append(list.node);
```

**Update**

More fleshed out example:

```
var pl = m.Playlist.fromURI("spotify:user:rhino_records:playlist:6sSFeKDgDxVR81YqNOuPf2");
var list = new v.List(pl, function (track) {
    return new views.Track(track, views.Track.FIELD.NAME |
                views.Track.FIELD.ARTIST |
                views.Track.FIELD.ALBUM);
});

document.body.appendChild(list.node);
```

`m` is the models namespace, `v` is the views namespace. For some reason, it's not quite working for me. It seems like the observer methods aren't being called at the moment. Seems to be a spotify backend thing though. It seems to get called eventually after some prodding

Comment: Im using the "standardized track listings"

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608692/how-to-use-standardized-track-listings-in-spotify-apps/10098480#10098480

sp = getSpotifyApi(1);

exports.init = init;

function init() {
    console.log("init()");
}   

var m = sp.require("sp://import/scripts/api/models");
var v = sp.require("sp://import/scripts/api/views");

var pl = m.Playlist.fromURI("spotify:user:rhino_records:playlist:6sSFeKDgDxVR81YqNOuPf2");

document.body.appendChild(list.node);

When I ad the var list function the playlist call breaks. Im stumped.

Comment: In your example Andrew, how do we call the playlist function?
everything loads fine, however I receive an error that says Playlist wasn't called in the .js.

Comment: Andrew, Thank you for this. I modified the View and it worked.

This is what I changed:
<!-- language: lang-js -->
var m = sp.require("sp://import/scripts/api/models");
var views = sp.require("sp://import/scripts/api/views");

var pl = m.Playlist.fromURI("spotify:user:rhino_records:playlist:6sSFeKDgDxVR81YqNOuPf2");
var list = new views.List(pl, function (track) 
{ return new views.Track(track, views.Track.FIELD.NAME |
    views.Track.FIELD.STAR |
                views.Track.FIELD.ARTIST |
                views.Track.FIELD.ALBUM);
});

document.body.appendChild(list.node);'

Thanks again.