# Spotify standardized track listing setting height of are before scroll bar appears

Tags: javascript, html, spotify

Using a code snippet like:

```
sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
var models = sp.require("sp://import/scripts/api/models");
var tpl = new models.Playlist();
var tempList = new views.List(tpl);
$(tempList.node).appendTo(document.getElementById("tracks"));
```

As described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608692/how-to-use-standardized-track-listings-in-spotify-apps), how can I change the default `<div>` size that the tracks are displayed in using the supplied Spotify model?

I want to be able to set it so that a scrollbar will appear if the size of the element is say 300px instead of the default 600px.

Looking at [this API](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/preview/reference/2b81e9e135.html), there doesn't appear to be a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the max-height property with css.

```
.sp-list {
    max-height: 300px;
}
```